# Encoding char in C#

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To which character encoding (Unicode version) set does a char object correspond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549054/to-which-character-encoding-unicode-version-set-does-a-char-object-correspond)

I'm a little afraid to ask this, as I'm sure its been asked before, but I can't find it. Its probably something obvious, but I've never studied encoding before.

```
int Convert(char c)
{
    return (int)c;
}
```

What encoding is produced by that method? I thought it might be ASCII (at least for <128), but doing the code below produced... smiley faces as the first characters? What? Definitely not ASCII...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + (char)i);
```

Comment: This may or may not answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549054/to-which-character-encoding-unicode-version-set-does-a-char-object-correspond

Comment: It did, thanks. How do I close this question as answered by that, or do you mind doing that? And to those of you looking at this question later, its UTF-16. I can't seem to find a table of the characters in utf-16 to verify the first ones are "smiley faces" but I assume they are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# `char` uses the UTF-16 encoding. The [language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), *1.3 Types and variables*, says:

> Character and string processing in C# uses Unicode encoding. The char type represents a UTF-16 code unit, and the string type represents a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

UTF-16 overlaps with ASCII in that the character codes in the ASCII range 0-127 mean the same thing in UTF-16 as in ASCII. The smiley faces in your program's output are presumably how your console interprets the non-printable characters in the range 0-31.

Comment: I would upvote a second time for pre-empting my "printing non-printable characters?" comment with your latest edit.

Comment: @BoltClock Perhaps we should campaign for diamond mods like yourself to get double votes!!!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Each char is a UTF-16 code point. However, you should use the proper Encoding class to ensure that the unicode is normalized. See
[C# and UTF-16 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697055/c-sharp-and-utf-16-characters)